github api (gh api) workflow runs endpoint not working with query parameters
when I run this, I get results gh api repos/myorg/myrepo/actions/workflows/my-workflow.yaml/runs. I wish to just grab runs from master branch, instead of doing that filtering afterwards. According to the docs "This endpoint will return up to 1,000 results for each search when using the following parameters: actor, branch, check_suite_id, created, event, head_sha, status."
However, if I add -f 'branch=master', -F 'branch=master', -f branch=master, or -F branch=master, I just get a 404:
gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest",
  "status": "404"
}

The branch name is correct. What is wrong with the parameters? Including headers does not work either and gives 404:
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  repos/myorg/myrepo/actions/workflows/my-workflow.yaml/runs -f "branch=master"

(I replaced org, repo, and workflow name with generics here.)

This endpoint wants HTTP GET requests, but if you add parameters to a GitHub CLI API request, it automatically switches to POST, see the manual:

The default HTTP request method is GET normally and POST if any parameters were added. Override the method with --method.

So:
gh api repos/myorg/myrepo/actions/workflows/my-workflow.yaml/runs \
    -f 'branch=master' \
    -X GET

where -X is short for --method.
